How can I reference a web service within Guidewire ClaimCenter using Guidewire Studio, utilizing a local WSDL file?
I'm looking to integrate a web service into my ClaimCenter project using Guidewire Studio. I have the WSDL file saved locally. Can I add a reference to this web service directly from the WSDL file within Guidewire Studio? If so, how can I accomplish this?
I manually copied the .wsdl file into the 'wsc' folder, but when attempting to upload the document, I encountered the following error message.
LocalClassNotFound
Version: ClaimCenter 10.0.3 Patch 3

What version of ClaimCenter are you using?

@SteveDrippsCentricConsulting ClaimCenter 10.0.3 Patch 3

What do you mean by "Can I add a reference to this web service directly from the WSDL file"? Can you please elaborate if you are trying to import the WSDL to get the generated web service classes or something else?

@AbhijayKumar I am trying to import the WSDL to get the generated web service classes.

Since the actual WSDL file has been provided to you (instead of a URL to fetch the WSDL from), the step of adding this WSDL to a WSC (Web Service Collection) in Guidewire Studio is a bit more complicated but not overly so.
Within the gsrc -> wsi -> remote package you would need to create a package for onbase and then create a new WSC within that onbase package. Then in the WSC you would need to "Add New Resource" and specify in the URL dialog box a file:/// URL to the place where your WSDL file is stored on your local machine. For example a URL that might work would be like this:
file:///c:/mywsdlfolder/mywsdl.wsdl
You may have to play around with the syntax to get it to work for your case.
After clicking OK Guidewire Studio will read the WSDL and create classes needed to call the web service. In your case if you intend to test this webservice, you will need to provide an override URL in the WSC because otherwise ClaimCenter would try to call a webservice on your local machine, which would not work because you aren't running that webservice locally, only importing the WSDL locally.
You may also have to run gwb genFromWsc to refresh the local files generated, but this should only be necessary if you receive an updated WSDL and put that WSDL in the same folder on your machine.
Simply copying the wsdl file into a wsc folder doesn't force studio to create the local classes necessary to call the web service.
